# C# file location to filebrowser in visual studio

Tags: c#

How can I change in C# file location to filebrowser

Code:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\hasta.txt");
string[] values;

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    values = lines[i].ToString().Split('|');
    string[] row = new string[values.Length];

    for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
    {
        row[j] = values[j].Trim();
    }

    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

I want to change this line

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\hasta.txt");
```

I tried this code:

```
OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
file.ShowDialog();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
string[] values;
```

but I get an error:

> CS1503 argument 1: Unable to convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog' to 'string'

Comment: What do you mean by "change to filebrowser"? Is this a Windows Forms app? A WPF app? Something else?

Comment: i want to change this side to openfiledialog but i get a string error. I use windows form app

Comment: "But I get string error" doesn't tell us what you've tried or precisely what error you're seeing. Please edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: i change it. Thank you for more idea

Comment: im beginner so sorry..

Comment: @BerkayKaplan `OpenFileDialog` is an object. To the selected filr name in the dialog, which is a string, use the `.FileName` property. See the [documentation for an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file.FileName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use it like this:

```
var result = file.ShowDialog(); //code pauses while user chooses a file
if(result != DialogResult.OK)   //the return value from ShowDialog tells us if the user clicked OK, Cancel, Yes, No etc
  return;                       //let the user cancel

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file.FileName); //file is a filedialog, get the chosen FileName (includes the path)
```

I think calling the OpenFileDialog "file" isn't great, because it's an OpenFiledialog, not a file. If you gave it a name that helped you remember it's a file dialog, then you'd be more likely to remember that the filename the user chooses is just one of many properties that an OpenFileDialog might have

A side note on File.ReadAllLines - it'll read the entire file into an array in memory. Your code then transfers this into another thing in memory, meaning you now effectively have all the data in memory twice. It would be a lower memory hit to use

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(path))
```

`ReadLines` reads the file gradually, meaning you don't have to buffer the entire thing. In a lot of cases it's preferable to use over ReadAllLines. It's relatively unimportant if we're talking about a few kilobytes text file, but one day you might be reading the lines out of a gigabyte file and knowing the difference between incremental reading and entire file buffering could be significant

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because `File.ReadAllLines` expects `string` input, representing path to a file, while you are passing there object of type `OpenFileDialog`, which cannot be converted to `string`.

What you should use it's `FileName` property of `OpenFileDialog`, as suggested in the other answer.

It's always useful to look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?view=netcore-3.1).